# Using the distance to slowly close in from Object to another moving Object

Tags: java, processing, controls, move

I'm using Processing to program a 2D mini game.
There is a car, you can control, and a cross **slowly** chasing after the car. Fairly simple. But now to my question.

How do I use only a **single Parameter** to calculate, in which direction the cross should move?

This is the calculation of the distance from Point A to Point B

```
float distance ( float xa, float ya, float xb, float yb ) 
{
  
  float dx = xa-xb;
  float dy = ya-yb;
  float dist = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);

  return dist;
}
```

To keep it Simple, there must be a possible and simple solution, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing has a `dist()` function that you should probably use instead of doing it yourself. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by single parameter, because you're going to need an X speed and a Y speed, so it's at least two parameters. But there are a few ways to go about finding them:

- You could scale your X and Y distances into a **unit vector**. The `PVector` class has useful function that would help with that. Again, more info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).
- Or you could use basic trigonometry to calculate the angle between the two objects. Google is your friend there. When you have the angle, you can use the `cos()` and `sin()` functions to calculate an X and Y speed.

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. So you should really try something, and post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck. Good luck.